# Am trying to setup the equivalent of python manage.py run server on windows but not working

Tags: python, django, windows, python-2.7

Situation:
Firstly I am very new to programming, let alone python. My friend and I are working on our first project together.  She has a MAC I have windows.  Originally, she was taking care of the backend and I was looking at the front end.  However, today we both synchd our code with GitHUb so that we can work together.  My friend's Python environment and server are all setup in her mac. I would like to do the same for windows. I tried running some commands below but they didn't work. I am running it in Python Command Line - please advise if this is incorrect.

Objective:
Now I need to make some changes to the HTML code. At the moment everything is running locally, if she on her mac after making changes runs python manage.py run server it provides her with a server address and she can see her work.  How can I setup the same.  I'm not too sure what to Google or where even to begin.  I don't need to setup a new project, just connect to the existing one.

I have tried the following:

```
python manage.py runserver 
python manage.py runserver "followed by server address"
```

I have:

- Installed Python
- Installed PyCharm
- Installed Django

This is the message i receive:

```
>>> `python manage.py runserver ###.#.#.#:####`
     python manage.py runserver ###.#.#.#:####
    File "<stdin>", Line 1
    python manage.py runserver ###.#.#.#:####
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am trying to connect to the same project she is working on.  Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: What error message was printed out when you entered that command? Always provide the error message, it's the most useful clue you can give us.

Comment: @MattDMo SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax

Comment: **Add requested information to the question by editing it, not in additional comments!**

Comment: What is the **full text** of the error/traceback?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or **complete error message/stacktrace** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't run that from Python, you run it from the command line.

(Note two things: why would you need to type "python" from inside Python; and this is true on both Mac and Windows, so you could have asked your colleague.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're running the command from the Python interactive prompt. You need to be running it from the Windows command prompt. Second, if the server is already running, you don't want to be re-running it.

I strongly suggest going through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/).